# convert code javascript to angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below code is in JavaScript, , i was worrking on javascript  , this script for satellite weather images animation . so am now use angularjs  can  i convert this code to the angularjs ?

```
var pic1=new Image()
pic1.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//61.jpg"
var pic2=new Image()
pic2.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//60.jpg"
var pic3=new Image()
pic3.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//59.jpg"
var pic4=new Image()
pic4.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//58.jpg"
var pic5=new Image()
pic5.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//57.jpg"
var pic6=new Image()
pic6.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//56.jpg"
var pic7=new Image()
pic7.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//55.jpg"
var pic8=new Image()
pic8.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//54.jpg"
var pic9=new Image()
pic9.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//53.jpg"
var pic10=new Image()
pic10.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//52.jpg"
var pic11=new Image()
pic11.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//51.jpg"
var pic12=new Image()
pic12.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//50.jpg"
var pic13=new Image()
pic13.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//49.jpg"
var pic14=new Image()
pic14.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//48.jpg"
var pic15=new Image()
pic15.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//47.jpg"
var pic16=new Image()
pic16.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//46.jpg"
var pic17=new Image()
pic17.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//45.jpg"
var pic18=new Image()
pic18.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//44.jpg"
var pic19=new Image()
pic19.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//43.jpg"
var pic20=new Image()
pic20.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//42.jpg"
var pic21=new Image()
pic21.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//41.jpg"
var pic22=new Image()
pic22.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//40.jpg"
var pic23=new Image()
pic23.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//39.jpg"
var pic24=new Image()
pic24.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//38.jpg"
var pic25=new Image()
pic25.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//37.jpg"
var pic26=new Image()
pic26.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//36.jpg"
var pic27=new Image()
pic27.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//36.jpg"
var pic28=new Image()
pic28.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//35.jpg"
var pic29=new Image()
pic29.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//34.jpg"
var pic30=new Image()
pic30.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//33.jpg"
var pic31=new Image()
pic31.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//32.jpg"
var pic32=new Image()
pic32.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//31.jpg"
var pic33=new Image()
pic33.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//30.jpg"
var pic34=new Image()
pic34.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//29.jpg"
var pic35=new Image()
pic35.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//28.jpg"
var pic36=new Image()
pic36.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//27.jpg"
var pic37=new Image()
pic37.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//26.jpg"
var pic38=new Image()
pic38.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//25.jpg"
var pic39=new Image()
pic39.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//24.jpg"
var pic40=new Image()
pic40.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//23.jpg"
var pic41=new Image()
pic41.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//22.jpg"
var pic42=new Image()
pic42.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//21.jpg"
var pic43=new Image()
pic43.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//20.jpg"
var pic44=new Image()
pic44.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//19.jpg"
var pic45=new Image()
pic45.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//18.jpg"
var pic46=new Image()
pic46.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//17.jpg"
var pic47=new Image()
pic47.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//16.jpg"
var pic48=new Image()
pic48.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//15.jpg"
var pic49=new Image()
pic49.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//14.jpg"
var pic50=new Image()
pic50.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//13.jpg"
var pic51=new Image()
pic51.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//12.jpg"
var pic52=new Image()
pic52.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//11.jpg"
var pic53=new Image()
pic53.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//10.jpg"
var pic54=new Image()
pic54.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//9.jpg"
var pic55=new Image()
pic55.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//8.jpg"
var pic56=new Image()
pic56.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//7.jpg"
var pic57=new Image()
pic57.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//6.jpg"
var pic58=new Image()
pic58.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//5.jpg"
var pic59=new Image()
pic59.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//4.jpg"
var pic60=new Image()
pic60.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//3.jpg"
var pic61=new Image()
pic61.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//2.jpg"
var pic62=new Image()
pic62.src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//1.jpg"

var counter=1
function animate(){
//does not animate if the browser does not support images
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.animation.src=eval("pic"+counter+".src")
if (counter<61)
counter++
else
counter=1
//controls the speed of the transition, in this case 100 means 100 milliseconds or 1/10 seconds
setTimeout("animate()",100)
}
animate()
```

html

```
  <img src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1//1.jpg" name="animation" style="width:auto;" class="img-responsive">
```

Can anybody tell me, how to do that?

Comment: You should read up a little bit on what arrays are before diving in too deep into frameworks. Also, using eval is (usually always) a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @CollinD i know about frameworks and i build some Personal app , but i am not convert code javascript to angularjs before

Comment: this isn't a code conversion service and finding image carousels is not difficult

Answer (score 0):

I would make an Angular controller to handle the view with the images. You could then use the `$interval` function to update this image source over a predefined amount of time. The third parameter of the `$interval` function allows a maximum repeat amount, so you don't have to worry about it iterating infinitely.

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('yourAppName')
  .controller('PageController',function($interval,$scope) {
    TIMING = 100 // ms of animation sequence
    TOTAL = 60 // total number of images
    $scope.currentIndex = 1;
    $interval(function() { $scope.currentIndex++ }, TIMING, TOTAL);
  });
```

HTML:

```
<img ng-src="http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1/{{currentIndex}}.jpg" name="animation" style="width:auto;" class="img-responsive">
```

Here is a CodePen showing that this solution will work. You may want to look at the basic formatting in AngularJS in my JS panel, so you can see how to create your application and bootstrap it to the HTML.

Also, it may be that the timing (100ms) you initially specified was a bit too fast for 60 images (60 * 100ms = 6000ms = 6s), at 6 seconds, which may have passed before the browser had a chance to load and display all 60 images.

http://codepen.io/frankrue/pen/XjzXGj

Comment: thanks for answer , but we have problem , this imges not animation just show last img 61 http://api.arabiaweather.com/localsat/gulf_ksa1/61.jpg

Comment: its same problem , see this link to show you what i mean http://meteoiraq.com/app/hot.html

Comment: Okay, here is the codepen again: http://codepen.io/frankrue/pen/XjzXGj

Does that do what you are looking to do?